# How can I use js to toggle the visibility of an element based on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

if I have hidden elements (dropdown list) that open on click on the parent element, how can I close them by clicking on another parent element in this case? here is the code i have in js

```
function toggleElement(elementId) {
  var element = document.querySelector(elementId);
  element.style.display = element.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("ContainerForMenu");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var target = this.getAttribute("data-target");
      toggleElement(target);
    });
  }
});
```

as a solution i tried this option but it doesn't work

```
function toggleElement(elementId) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.child-element');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  var element = document.querySelector(elementId);
  element.style.display = "block";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("ContainerForMenu");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var target = this.getAttribute("data-target");
      toggleElement(target);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of toggleing style, use a class with CSS and then use `element.classList.toggle()`

Comment: As a solution to what? You haven't said what's wrong with the first code snippet. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Does your `data-target` have `#` at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Follow my code you can use toggle  toggle the visibility of an element based on a button click...

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```